# How to 'nerdctl run' inside another container like DooD or DinD?

Tags: containerd, docker-in-docker, nerdctl

What volumes do I need to mount etc. to get nerdctl run to work inside of another container?

PS I know about the security issues. I need to know how to do this anyway.